# HTML5 - basic keyframe two object

Tags: html, css

how to create animation with two object. after the first object have animation, the second object will have animation.

example :
keyframe (1s) : Object 1 size 2px

keyframe (1s) : Object 2 size 2px

keyframe (3s) : Object 1 size 5px

keyframe (5s) : Object 2 size 5px

image : http://postimg.org/image/yyoqmbro9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `animation-delay` property of the 2nd object to `6s`. This will make the 2nd animation start after 6 seconds

Comment: how about when start, the visibility 2nd object is hide after 6 second visibility 2nd object is show. can you help me? @Sidsec9

Comment: since you're using `keyframe` animations, you can `keyframe` `opacity:0` between `0s to 6s` and then set `opacity:1` at `6s`